# Plotting two objects using a 4-item list

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this simulator (gravitation) I've been working on, and I've dissected the equations, math, etc. and it's totally legitimate. However, when I animate the thing I get weird behavior. I'd rather not bore everyone with the entire script because it's sorta lengthy, but the method I'm calling in `line.set` under the `animate(i)` function returns a list of four values, which are the positions of my two particles in Cartesian (x,y) coordinates. For example my list looks like:

[1.2, 3.2, 4.5, 5.1]

where the first index is the x-position of the first particle, the second index is the y-position and likewise for the the last two elements corresponding to the second particle (indices 2 and 3).

My question is whether the `line.set_data(force.updatePosition(dt))` *should* be working the way I think it does, i.e. plotting the first particle with indices `0` and `1` and particle two with indices `2` and `3`, or am I missing the point? The plotting works, the particles show up, but they get weird, non-sensical movement.

If it's completely necessary [here](https://gist.github.com/bodieskate/9499025) is the script in its entirety...again it's long-ish that's why I didn't post it directly. Also, it's pretty messy as I'm still fighting with it and haven't cleaned it up yet.

**Tl;DR** Should `line.set_data()` be able to plot two separate objects if it is fed a list with 4 items?

```
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    line.set_data(force.updatePosition(dt))
    return line,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say:

```
Definition: l.set_data(self, *args)
Docstring:
Set the x and y data

ACCEPTS: 2D array (rows are x, y) or two 1D arrays
```

So I imagine you want to give it two lists:

```
line.set_data([x1, x2], [y1, y2])
```

But it seems that `force.updatePosition` already returns a list of two lists(`[pos1]+[pos2]`), so you can maybe try:

```
line.set_data(np.transpose(force.updatePosition(dt)))
```

My opinion is you might be better off keeping all this info in arrays and remove half the lines of your code, since you write every line two or four times for each element.

Comment: I agree with your opinion...I'd like to say it's super-repetative just because I'm 'fighting with it', but...yeah, I should be more on top of the methods/functions thing. In any case, I have tried the `force.updatePosition(dt)` and I get similar (strange) behavior.